# Python Declare variables iteratively

Tags: python, loops, variables, initialization, iteration

I'm working on an assignement in wich I need to print a "diamond" after the user typed in the dimensions he wanted. Example ;

If the user types 5 it looks like this :

```
  |
 |||
|||||
 |||
  |
```

If the user types 10 it looks like this :

```
      |
     |||
    |||||
   |||||||
  |||||||||
  |||||||||
   |||||||
    |||||
     |||
      |
```

My idea is to initialize an array for each row that I need to print but I don't know how to automaticly initialize multiple arrays corresponding to the number the user typed in.

Any help is welcome and feel free to tell me if you thnk I'm going totaly the wrong way!

Comment: `row = [ "some_char" ] * 10`

Comment: get the user input dimensions and then do a for loop and print arrays depending on the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it helps you can use "array" (or rather two-dimensional list).

To create row with 10 letters "X"

```
row = [ "X" ] * 10
```

But to create "array" with 10 rows you can't do

```
array = [  [ "X" ] * 10  ] * 10
```

because you get all rows as references to the same space in memory.

You need

```
array = []

for i in range(10)
    row = [ "X" ] * 10
    array.append(row)
```

Or shorter

```
array = [ [ "X" ] * 10 for i in range(10) ]
```

(in place of `"X"` you can use space `" "`)

Comment: Thank you! It does help! :)